# xcode cocos2d arc multiple errors

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, malloc

I've got a big project on cocos2d with ARC enabled. Some days ago I began to get theese strange errors:

outfighter(16344,0x601000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1c8eaa00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

outfighter(16359,0x3afe8b78) malloc: *** error for object 0x1c5da4e4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

outfighter(16374,0x705000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1cd6fa60: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I can not even find out what place in my code causes theese errors. They appears very unexpected in very differrent parts of project

Comment: Did you follow the piece of advice you were given?

Comment: (I help you: "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug")

Comment: post the code where these errors occur. Do you use free/malloc or related functions?

Comment: I am using arc, so I do not free or alloc memory. "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug" - I can not do it case I am a noob